# Invoking functions written with CUDA and Thrust C++ in my C# 5 .NET 4.5 application

Tags: c#, .net, cuda, thrust, physx.net

I'm getting a grasp on invoking C++ functions from an application written in C# 5 and .NET 4.5.  I am working on developing an indie game and have need of CUDA and PhysX, so this capability is important to me.  I discovered Thrust, a C++ library that allows easier implementation of CUDA.

Now I'm trying to figure out if it's possible using Thrust C++ to create a .DLL containing my graphic specific functions that will utilize the GPU.... Then invoking these functions from my managed code when needed.  Has anyone done anything like this?  Experiences?  Anything I'm confused on?  Other options?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

What you are attempting can be done. Just remember that Thrust is mostly full of header files, like STL or Boost. The strategy you use with STL or Boost to generate DLL files, should work for you with Thrust too.